# Упаковка списка ip адресов

Tags: python, ip

такое задание у меня: у меня есть список около 3к айпишников, мне нужно найти в них подсети (первые три октета) оставить один айпишник в виде xxx.xxx.xxx.0/маска.

```
with open ('dropIP') as f:    
    lines = f.readlines()
    lst = []
    lst2 = []
    count = 0
    
    for item in lines:
        lst.append(item)
    print(len(lst))
    lst.sort()
    #for item in lst:
        #print(item)
    for item in lst:
        #print('Сравнение '+item)
        for item2 in lst:
            if item.rsplit('.',1)[0] == item2.rsplit('.',1)[0]:
               count += 1
               if count >= 2:
                   lst.remove(item2)
                   print(item2)
               else: continue   
    print(len(lst))
```

вот пример кода, но у меня такое ощущение что я в не правильном направлении иду

Comment: Вы же все равно не пытаетесь вычислить реальную маску, у вас все подсети будут класса C. в таком случае просто читайте все ip. оставляйте только три первых октета, делайте из них set  - и вперед

Comment: пока набросок кода, я в ступор встал когда нужно было найти подсети

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, для получения подсетей класса C для ваших исходных данных, можно сделать просто:

```
iplist = []

with open("ip_list.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        ip = line.rsplit(".", 1)[0]
        ip = f"{ip}.0/255"
        iplist.append(ip)

iplist = set(iplist)
```

Comment: вот тут то и кроется подводный камень, мне нужно будет вычислить маску, в зависимости от кол-ва хостов в подсети

Comment: @ГеоргийЖиленко для вычисления маски знания количества хостов не достаточно. либо вам придется перебирать маски так, чтобы все хосты подсети класса C в нее попадали.

Comment: ну почему нет? Нашло два вхождения допусти то это /30, нашло 4,5,6 вхождений то /29. Вот такого плана

Comment: @ГеоргийЖиленко как просто у вас получается. а если эти 4-6 адресов с 29 маской в разных подсетях? а их (подсетей) при такой маске будет 32 штуки.

Comment: ну вот если 32 вхождения найдется, то это уже /27 маска будет

Comment: @ГеоргийЖиленко вы точно понимаете то, о чем говорите? а если бродкаст разный у адресов? а почему не /24 маска? может у вас один адрес - .1, а второй - .250?

Comment: это уже ньюансы, у меня щас задача сгруппировать хосты по маске

Comment: @ГеоргийЖиленко это не нюансы, это то, без чего вы не сможете "сгруппировать хосты по маске", кроме как тупо дав им /24

Comment: хм.... и как же поступить тогда